# How to add and remove object from vector<unique_ptr>...?

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr

I have two functions like this. When I add a new object, everything is fine, but if I try to add an object that was already in this vector, the application just closes. I am running the `unique_ptr` destructor after removing from a vector. How to fix it?

```cpp
void AddObject(GameObject* obj) {
    objects().push_back(std::move(unique_ptr<GameObject>(obj)));
}
        
void DeleteObject(GameObject* obj) {
    for (auto itr = objects().begin(); itr != objects().end(); ++itr) {
        if ((*itr)->ID == obj->ID) {
            objects().erase(std::move(itr));
            itr->~unique_ptr();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I am running the unique_ptr deconstructor after removing from a vector.` Why? And whats all this moving for? `std::move(unique_ptr<GameObject>(obj))` Use `emplace_back`.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I'm sorry I needed to use the fields and methods of subclasses in a vector with a superclass type. The first way to implement this that I found, and that worked, was using unique_ptr.

Comment: @tkausl objects().emplace_back(std::move(unique_ptr<GameObject>(obj)));
did not help

Comment: `objects().emplace_back(obj); `.

Comment: @tkausl same :(

Comment: Get rid of the manual destructor call. Its just wrong.

Comment: @tkausl Did, but as expected this is not the root of the problem. The delete function does not work somehow, it is on it that the program dies 100%. But even if you just add the same object more than 2 times, then it will also crash

Comment: `But even if you just add the same object more than 2 times` Well, you're not supposed to have multiple `unique_ptr`s which own the same object.

Comment: @tkausl Yes, I figured it out, so my code does not give 2 identical objects to a vector, I delete them using the DeleteObject function. But either the function does not completely delete the object, or it crashes inside.

Answer (score 0):

Everything about the code you have shown is wrong.

`AddObject()` should take a `unique_ptr<GameObject>` as input, not a raw `GameObject*` pointer, eg:

```cpp
void AddObject(unique_ptr<GameObject> obj) {
    objects().push_back(std::move(obj));
}
```

Otherwise, you risk the caller being able to add the same object multiple times, and thus it would be managed by multiple `unique_ptr`s.

A better option would be to not let the caller create its own objects to begin with.  Have the caller specify the object type and constructor arguments, but let `AddObject()` handle the actual creation, eg:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void AddObject(Args&&... args) {
    objects().push_back(std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

As for `DeleteObject()`, `erase()`ing an element from a vector *invalidates iterators* that refer to elements at/after the erasure point, *including the iterator that is being erased*. Your loop is not accounting for that.  `erase()` returns an iterator to the element following the one that is being erased, so if you are not going to `break` your loop (can you have multiple objects with the same `ID` value?) then you need to use that `iterator` to continue your loop correctly.

Also, directly calling a destructor on an object that was not created with `placement-new` is *undefined behavior*.  In this case, there is no reason to destroy the `unique_ptr`s manually at all.  They will get destroyed automatically when they go out of scope when removed from the vector.

If you intend for `DeleteObject()` to search for a specific object, then it should look for that specific object pointer, not an ID:

```cpp
void DeleteObject(GameObject* obj) {
    auto &objs = objects();
    for (auto itr = objs.begin(); itr != objs.end(); ++itr) {
        if (itr->get() == obj) {
            objs.erase(itr);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
void DeleteObject(GameObject* obj) {
    auto &objs = objects();
    auto itr = std::find_if(objs.begin(), objs.end(),
        [=](auto &ptr){ return ptr.get() == obj; }
    );
    if (itr != objs.end()) {
        objs.erase(itr);
    }
}
```

If you intend for `DeleteObject()` to search for an ID, then it should take an ID as input, not an object pointer:

```cpp
void DeleteObject(int ID) {
    auto &objs = objects();
    for (auto itr = objs.begin(); itr != objs.end(); ++itr) {
        if ((*itr)->ID == ID) {
            itr = objs.erase(itr);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
void DeleteObject(int ID) {
    auto &objs = objects();
    auto itr = std::find_if(objs.begin(), objs.end(),
        [=](auto &ptr){ return ptr->ID == ID; }
    );
    if (itr != objs.end()) {
        objs.erase(itr);
    }
}
```

Or, if multiple objects can have the same ID (?):

```cpp
void DeleteObject(int ID) {
    auto &objs = objects();
    for (auto itr = objs.begin(); itr != objs.end(); ) {
        if ((*itr)->ID == ID) {
            itr = objs.erase(itr);
        }
        else {
            ++itr;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
void DeleteObject(int ID) {
    auto &objs = objects();
    objs.erase(
        std::remove_if(objs.begin(), objs.end(),
            [=](auto &ptr){ return ptr->ID == ID; }
        ),
        objs.end()
    );

    // or, in C++20 and later:

    std::erase_if(objs,
        [=](auto &ptr){ return ptr->ID == ID; }
    );
}
```